# How to map values from nested Typescript object to properties of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, nested-object

In a project that I'm working on, we're using the Angular library called [formly](https://formly.dev/) to create our forms dynamically.

Currently, the form configuration is hardcoded as a Typescript object called `mockForm`. All of the properties in `mockForm` are hardcoded besides the `options` property in objects whose `type` property equals `'select'`:

**mockForm**

```
export const mockForm = {
    name: 'root',
    subSections: [
        {
            name: 'Client',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Contact Information'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Insurance Information'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Sales',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Overview',
                    subSections: [
                        {
                            name: 'Overview - A',
                            fields: [
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldA1',
                                    type: 'input',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'A1',
                                        required: true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldA2',
                                    type: 'select',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'A2',
                                        required: true,
                                        options: []
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Overview - B',
                            fields: [
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldB1',
                                    type: 'input',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'B1',
                                        required: false
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldB2',
                                    type: 'select',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'B2',
                                        required: false,
                                        options: []
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I would like to populate the `options` property by using an API called which returns the following object:

**API return**

```
{
    "multi_value_fields": {
        "fieldA2": [
            "froodian@outlook.com",
            "gastown@sbcglobal.net",
            "dgriffith@me.com",
            "maradine@live.com",
            "samavati@icloud.com",
            "naupa@comcast.net"
        ],
        "fieldB2": [
            "<3m",
            "<6m",
            "<9m",
            "<12m",
            "+12m",
            "N/A"
        ]
    }
}
```

The object returned from the API call returns a JSON whose properties are the `key` values from `mockForm` whose property `type` equals `'select'`; and the values of these JSON properties represent the dropdown options of the form.

The intended outcome should be the following:

```
export const mockForm = {
    name: 'root',
    subSections: [
        {
            name: 'Client',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Contact Information'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Insurance Information'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Sales',
            subSections: [
                {
                    name: 'Overview',
                    subSections: [
                        {
                            name: 'Overview - A',
                            fields: [
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldA1',
                                    type: 'input',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'A1',
                                        required: true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldA2',
                                    type: 'select',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'A2',
                                        required: true,
                                        options: [
                                            "froodian@outlook.com",
                                            "gastown@sbcglobal.net",
                                            "dgriffith@me.com",
                                            "maradine@live.com",
                                            "samavati@icloud.com",
                                            "naupa@comcast.net"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Overview - B',
                            fields: [
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldB1',
                                    type: 'input',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'B1',
                                        required: false
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    key: 'fieldB2',
                                    type: 'select',
                                    templateOptions: {
                                        label: 'B2',
                                        required: false,
                                        options: [
                                            "<3m",
                                            "<6m",
                                            "<9m",
                                            "<12m",
                                            "+12m",
                                            "N/A"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I haven't experienced a scenario like this, and I'm not so sure on how to approach this (Should I start with the JSON properties and map back to `mockForm`? Would I need to manually iterate through `mockForm` in order to populate from the API call?)

Comment: You might be using TypeScript but this doesn't seem TypeScript-specific.  Looks more like a JavaScript question to me.  Maybe you should add the JavaScript tag?

Answer (score 1):

your JSON **mockForm** is very typical.
If it remains the same then you must manually iterate over the bottom leaf i.e., `mokeForm.subSections[1].subSections` and then loop there to match the **label** & **type**.

Otherwise, you need to write parse which iterates all over mokeForm JSON & assign required options are respective places.